# Как сбилдить apk файл в Unity

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, я новичок в Untiy. Проблема такая... Я хочу сделать apk файл через Building Setting в Unity, но у меня нет кнопки Build, вместо неё у меня Export.Что делать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Можете скрин показать?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас поставлена галочка на Export Project - самая верхняя в настройках Building Settings.